# Testing my application on my device

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to test my phone 7 application in my device that I have developed.please guide me on how to install my app in a device?And Which Windows Phone 7 Device is Good for Testing?

Answer (score 1):

[It's covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928362%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), under the section titled "Deploying to a Physical Windows Phone Device".  It requires an developer unlocked device.

Comment: You must have a developer account to unlock the Phone.  There is a price for that, though if you join DreamSpark, it is also free (or was last I checked anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have done it already you need to register your phone as a developer phone.
http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership

Then you need to download and install Zune, when you have don that it just to plugin you phone and choose to deploy to phone instead of emulator in visual studio.

Comment: thereafter you still need to go to "Windows Phone Developer Registration" for developer unlock before you can deploy the app to your device

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 7.1 SDK and Zune installed:

1. Goto start search for Windows Phone Developer Registration.
2. After registering you can debug on the phone from Visual Studio by selecting target as "Windows Phone Device".